# A static method parseInt(char[]) that converts an array of numeric characters to an int value

Tags: java, arrays, casting

Here's my code

```
public static int[] parseInt(char[] myChar)
{      
    int[] myInt = new int[myChar.length];
    for(int x = 0; x < myChar.length; x++)
    {
                myInt[x] = (int)myChar[x];
    }
    return myInt;
}
```

When I `System.out.println(object.parseInt(myChar));` with values `{'1','2','3'}` I would expect it to print `myInt` with the corresponding unicode values for `{'1','2','3'}`.

Instead I get `[I@15db9742`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are getting int[] as results which is object. Loop over the results and print individual element.

Comment: Your method does not convert to an int value. It converts to an array of integers. Your title seems to indicate that for an array `[1,2,3]` your are supposed to return the number 123.

Comment: _I would expect it to_ Why?

Answer (score 1):

That because you are printing the object, hence java shows:

```
[I - the name of the type (in this case it is one dimensional [ array of int) 
@ - joins the string together
15db9742the hashcode of the object.
```

the memory address by default. You can use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(parseInt(array)));
```

Comment: It's not the memory address. It's a concatenation of the object class name and its hash code.

Comment: "are see the memory address" that is not true. We are seeing hexadecimal hashcode. This value can be based on memory location, but doesn't reflect it (object can be moved in memory...)

Comment: @RealSkeptic very true, I'll update it